# Setting :root custom properties inside Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, shadow-dom

my use case is basically the following: I'm building a component library which should render a component in a web component using shadowRoot.

I have two CSS files:

`component-library.css` styles the component library and should not leak into the web components (I'm aware that they do when the components use `inherit`. This is fine.).

`project.css` is the global CSS file for the project, defining lots of custom properties inside `:root {}`. I am NOT able to change that.

What I now want is to use `project.css` inside the shadowRoot to style the components. The reason that it should be inside the shadowRoot is that I don't want this file to affect the component library.

Right now, when I'm trying to implement it, everything works as I want it to except that the custom properties from `project.css` is missing.
My understanding is that this can't work as the `project.css` would have to use `:host {}` instead of `:root {}`.

Is that correct? Would there be any way to achieve this though?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You would need to use `:host` instead of `:root`

Comment: Yeah, that's also my understanding. I just wanted to get it confirmed… Thanks :)